# Delete system image file on kenzo

Tags: storage

As the subject line suggests .Can i delete the system image partition on my kenzo?Theres a system  partition as well.Both show up on twrp recovery. Ive been looking everywhere for an answer, but cannot seem to find one .
Im trying to free up some space .
Can anyone help?

Comment: `userdata` is the only partition you should be concerned with when dealing low-storage issue. Tinkering with rest of the partitions would do no good to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably confusing TWRP backups with existing partitions here. TWRP backs up in two different ways:

- image: a disk image (i.e. a block-wise copy)
- tar: disk contents (i.e. a file-wise copy)

So you have two backups of the same partition here. Also see my answer on [Trying to understand the options in TWRP backup](/q/215683/16575) for more details.

Moreover, if you want to "free up space", `/system` is the wrong place to start. Rather check with the questions linked from our [insufficient-memory tag wiki](/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for this task.